# can I access to insert data from main method creating a object of Generic Class

Tags: java, arrays, generics

**Sorry, I Edited My code to make it simple.**

```
class ClassExampleOfGeneric<T>{
   public T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[3] ;
}
    
public class Generic {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var x = new ClassExampleOfGeneric<String>();
        
        x.arr[0]="hjgh";  // can I insert "String" at the end "new Object[3]" converted into string array 
        x.arr[1]"lol";
        x.arr[2]="mnasdas";
           
        System.out.println(x.arr.length); //<--- Here can i  retrive from array 
   }
}
```

**Problem is Show Below**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at Generic.main(Generic.java:34)

I am new in java. I didn't to able to catch the error.

Comment: As it's already was said - it's not a good idea to use arrays with generics, you might get weird runtime erros, so just drop that idea. Consider `List` instead. Also what do you mean by _inserting "String" at the end "new Object[3]"_? If you want to change the size of an array then it's not possible. Once you declare an array with certain size it can not be changed. Again `List` can help here too as you can add new elements to the list easily.

Answer (score 4):

That is a bizarre situation and possibly a bug. However, it is quite moot - this is *not* the right approach. You're committing multiple style infractions; things that are not neccessary and aren't the way that 99.9% of all java code is written. When you rewrite your code this problem goes away:

1. Casting `Object[]` to `T[]` is flat out **wrong**, and that warning you get during compilation is trying to tell you that you now have a lie in your code. `Object[]` is NOT a `T[]`: Unlike with, say, `List<String>`, where you can't get the String part back out, with an array you very much can: `arr.getClass().getComponentType()`. The right approach in such a situation (when you have a need to have a generic collection) is not to use arrays at all, and to use e.g. a `List<T>`. If you somehow MUST use an array, then the right approach is to just have an `Object[]` array, and cast every time you need to do so. This is, for example, how java's own `ArrayList` is written. Remember, arrays and generics **just do not work together**, so don't try. Then you get crazy errors like this if you do, which is proof that you shouldn't be doing this.
2. More generally you should not have public fields. Especially a field that is a hack / a lie, like `arr` is here. public arrays in general is a very bad idea; you can't make them immutable or unmodifiable, so you're really giving away any shot at keeping control of your API if you do this. It's also not idiomatic java code.

Simplest solution:

```
class ClassExampleOfGeneric<T> {
    private Object[] arr = new Object[3];

    public void add(T item) {
          arr[2] = item ;
     }
 
     public void getArrEle() {
         for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
             System.out.println(arr[i]);
         }
     }

     public T get(int idx) {
         return (T) arr[i]; // cast here!
     }
 }
```

NB: Nevertheless, that calling `.length` on an array whose type is not actually aligned due to generics violations ends up causing a CCEx is bizarre. However, that warning you get during compilation? It gives the 'right' to the compiler to make this happen, so while bizarre, it is not a bug in the strictest sense, and trying to report this on e.g. bugs.openjdk.net is 99% likely to be ignored or disregarded as 'works as intended; wontfix'. The only feasible path is not to cast `Object[]` to `T[]`, because Object[] just isn't T[]. In general, having a `T[]` anywhere is a mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66294093/7804477 - I tried adding a method to retrieve the length inside the class. But that is working fine. Any idea why it is not throwing an error?

Comment: @rzwitserloot First of I am new i java And I Edited My code .can u  please revisit my code and what is wrong in my code i  know this should be  ` private T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[3] ; ` but if i make it ` public ` then try to insert and retirve data  is it possible ?.

Comment: As I told you, Wasim, you can't have `T[]`, there is no need for it and it causes whole heaps of trouble. _Generics and arrays do not play nice with each other_, that's just a fact, and not solvable with code trickery. I showed you in this example how to avoid T[] in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot)'s answer explains the issue and it is better to opt for `List` implementations while using generics. But as a workaround, if you add a length getter method inside `ClassExampleOfGeneric` then there will not be an error.

```java
public int getLength() {
    return arr.length;
}
```